# In Angular Storybook, how to show only @Input() in the controls section?

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Currently in Angular Storybook, it shows every public thing in my component as a control like this :

[image]

I want it to show only the "Input" category and ignore everything else. Is there a way to do this ?